# Python - Regex not replacing directory strings

Tags: python, regex, operating-system

I'm using the following function to remove a specific string pattern from files in a directory:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(path):
   os.rename(filename, filename.replace(r'^[A-Z]\d\d\s-\s[A-Z]\d\d\s-\s$', ''))
```

The pattern is as follows, where A is any capital letter, and # is any number between 0-9:

> A## - A## -

My regex matches this format on regex101. When I run the above function, it completes without error, however no directory names change. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` string method does not support regular expressions.

You need to import the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and use its [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method.

So your code might look like this:

```
import os
import re
for filename in os.listdir(path):
   os.rename(filename, re.sub(r'^[A-Z]\d\d\s-\s[A-Z]\d\d\s-\s', '', filename))
```

But don't forget about flags and such.

Edit: Removed `$` from the pattern as the filenames don't end there.

Comment: Odd, I've tried this but it's still not working for some reason, it completes without error however nothings changed.

Comment: @LaurieBamber could you give us a couple sample filenames?

Comment: File 1: 'S01 - E01 - Something Here', File 2: 'S01 - E02 - Something Different'.... File k: 'S07 - E06 - Something Different'

Comment: @LaurieBamber You have the string end marker (`$`) in your pattern, but the file name does not end there, so it doesn't match. Just remove the `$` from your pattern.

Comment: Gentleman, thats done it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LaurieBamber Happy to help. Don't forget to mark the question as solved (answer as accepted). =)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
filename='A11 - A22 - '#A## - A## -
re.sub(filename,r'^[A-Z]\d\d\s-\s[A-Z]\d\d\s-\s', '')
```

Comment: Thanks, this still isn't working for some reason with my code though.

Comment: can you print the output after executing the above code?

Comment: My mistake, as pointed out by Chillie I was incorrectly using the $ symbol to finish the pattern. Thanks for the help anyway.